# export R neuralnet package model to PMML

Tags: r, predictive-modeling

when I look into the *R package* `pmml`, I found that, it is possible to directly export `nnet` model into `PMML` format.

But actually I am using `neuralnet` package since it has more features and flexibility.

The problem is:

How can I export `neuralnet` model to `PMML` format, I checked `pmml` package, it doesn't work.

Any other options like transform `neuralnet` model to `nnet` model, or some other `PMML` packages to use? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You already mentioned the alternatives...

- convert the `neuralnet` object to a `nnet` class object
- implement `pmml.neuralnet()`

Both `pmml`, `nnet` and `neuralnet` packages are easy to read. You can find the source code [over cran.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html)

I think implementing `pmml.neuralnet()` might be the cleanest. You can just copy-paste the current [`pmml.nnet()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmml/index.html)  method, call it `pmml.neturalnet()` and make the necessary changes. Should not take more than a day's work.

ps: It would be cool if you'd sent your function to `neuralnet` authors afterwards of course, and link it from here. :)

Comment: I already contacted the author Frauke Guthener who wrote the `neuralnet`, but he seems to have no interest on transform `nn` model to `pmml` model. and I started to work on the suggestions you gave. and since I am full-day employee and have a girlfriend who likes to travel a lot... I can't foresee the date i will finish that thing. I will paste a link for that work when I finish it. and thanks @Ricardo Cruz